# How to edit the Sitecore Image Field from codebehind

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7.2

I have a sitecore Item '`CurrentItem`' with a field "`image`". I am editing it from code behind as follows:

```
//Get the Image from /sitecore/media library/Images/Test
Item imageItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("{AEBB3071-3462-405C-9CD3-A2B515B343D1}")
//Edit   
CurrentItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
CurrentItem["image"] = imageItem.ToString();
CurrentItem.Editing.EndEdit();
```

**PS:** `imageItem` is a picture under `/sitecore/media library/Images/Test`

I also tried with `CurrentItem["image"] = imageItem.Paths.Path;` But still no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to take the field as `ImageField` and set the MediaID property to the ID of the MediaItem:

```
//Get the Image from /sitecore/media library/Images/Test
Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem imageItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("{AEBB3071-3462-405C-9CD3-A2B515B343D1}")
//Edit   
CurrentItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
var imageField = CurrentItem.Fields["image"] as ImageField;
imageField.MediaID = imageItem.ID;
imageField.MediaPath = imageItem.MediaPath;
CurrentItem.Editing.EndEdit();
```

Also you can take a look at [this](http://www.matthewkenny.com/2013/10/setting-sitecore-image-field-updated/) blog post for more explanations for the post 6.X Versions.

Comment: I had to cast the ImageField instead of using `as` for it to work. Example: `(ImageField) CurrentItem.Fields["image"];`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField class to update an Image field. For example,
to update the Image field named ImageField in the /Sitecore/Content/Home item in the Master
database to the /Sitecore/Media Library/Images/Sample image:

```
Sitecore.Data.Database master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item home = master.GetItem("/sitecore/content/home");
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item sampleItem =
 master.GetItem("/sitecore/media library/images/sample");
Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem sampleMedia =
 new Sitecore.Data.Items.MediaItem(sampleItem);
Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField imageField = home.Fields["imagefield"];
if (imageField.MediaID != sampleMedia.ID )
{
 home.Editing.BeginEdit();
 imageField.Clear();
 imageField.Src = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(sampleMedia);
 imageField.MediaID = sampleMedia.ID;
 imageField.MediaPath = sampleMedia.MediaPath;
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sampleMedia.Alt))
 {
 imageField.Alt = sampleMedia.Alt;
 }
 else
 {
 imageField.Alt = sampleMedia.DisplayName;
 }
 home.Editing.EndEdit();
}
```

Please check https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/content_api_cookbook-usletter.pdf on 4.1.7 How to Access Image Fields